# Identify possible pair of factors from a product

Tags: c++, beginner, factors

This is my first C++ program (not counting "hello world") and I'd like to know if there are some semantic mistakes or if I could rewrite the code in a more simple way.

It performs brute-force factorisation of the number provided on standard input.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int f1 = 0;
    int f2 = 0;
    int p;
    int increment = 1;
    cin >> p;
    if ((f1 && f2) == p) {
        cout << f1 << "x" << f2 << "=" << p;
    }
    else if (p < 00) {
        cout << "Insert a positive number";
    }

    while (
        ( (f1 && f2) != p) && (f1 < p) && (f2 <= p) ) {

        f1++;
        if (f1 * f2 == p) {
            cout << f1 << "x" << f2 << "=" << p << "\n";
        }
        f2 = increment;
        if (f1 == p) {
            increment++;
                f1 = 0;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. When you copy the code above into a development environment: does it compile *as is*?

Comment: What is ``f1 && f2`` supposed to be? Please research what the ``&&`` operator does, and rethink your code.

Comment: Have you tested this code and does it work?

Comment: @greybeard it compiles and seems to give the proper answer.

Comment: @dumetrulo is my use of && wrong? It was supposed to be something like "while the value stored in f1 AND f2 is not equal the value of p [...] Is this logic wrong?

Comment: @Toriality Yes, it's incorrect. If you want to test whether both ``f1`` and ``f2`` are not equal to ``p``, you have to test it separately: ``(f1 != p) && (f2 != p)``. Together with the other conditions in that line, it can be simplified to just ``(f1 < p) && (f2 < p)``, given that when both ``f1`` and ``f2`` are less than ``p``, neither can be equal to it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't `using namespace std;` - this namespace isn't designed for wholesale import like that.

Import `<cstdlib>` to declare `std::system()` - though note that almost any use of this function makes your code highly platform-specific (that just gives a `sh: pause: not found` error here, for example).

Never ignore the return value from `std::system` or from streaming with `>>`.

Error messages should go to `std::cerr` and end with a newline (and we should return early in the error case, rather than continuing to the `while` loop).

`if ((f1 && f2) == p)` is a highly unconventional way of writing `if (p == 0)`.  Don't make it unnecessarily hard to read.

In the `while` condition, `(f1 && f2) != p)` can only be false when `p` is `1`, so just treat that case separately, before the loop.

Prefer pre-increment (`++x`) to post-increment (`x++`) in C++ code when not using the result.  Here, with integers, the compiler can optimize to the same code, but with more complex types, that's not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

Only include the headers needed, `cstdio` is not needed for this code.

The first if,

```
    if ((f1 && f2) == p) {
        cout << f1 << "x" << f2 << "=" << p;
    }
```

is not needed.

It might be better if the second if was

```
    if (p <= 0) {
        cout << "Insert a positive number";
    }
```

It might also be better if the above code either exited the program or was within a loop that would allow the user to enter a positive number.

### Avoid Using Namespace `std`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.